# Error propagation of complex numbers

Tags: data-transformation, covariance, error, complex-numbers

I have a problem with coordinate transformation of complex numbers and their covariances:

Let's say I want to do some statistic with a series of complex numbers and for this, I have to work in the Cartesian plane to avoid the jumps in the $r,\phi$-plane.
Afterwards I want to get the amplitude and phase from my complex number with the covariances!

One way would be to view the complex numbers as polar coordinates and there I get a non-complex covariance matrix.
The other way would be to see the complex numbers as complex numbers. Then the elements of the covariance matrix are <s>imaginary</s> complex numbers themselves$^1$ (at least the cross-covariances have non-zero imaginary numbers).

Ok, now I want to do the error propagation/transformation ($J \Sigma J^T$, with Jacobians and the original covariance matrix)$^2$. They are quite similar for Polar coordinates and complex numbers. Therefore I expect real elements for the covariance matrix of the error transformation from the polar coordinates but complex elements for the covariance matrix of the error transformation from complex plane (I verified this by hand).

In the end, I have phase and amplitude with a complex valued covariance matrix. Does this make sense? This looks a little bit wrong to me...

In both ways, I linearize the error during the transformation - so would the imaginary parts vanish, if I do it on some other way? (No clue how.)

Edit:

$^1$ covariance entries in the i,j-Matrix are given by (with μ=0): $\sigma_{ij} = E([Z_i][Z_j]^H)$. For any complex numbers $a+ib$ and $c+id$ this becomes: $(a+ib)(c−id)=ac−bd+i(bc−ad)$. And $bc−ad$ is not zero (Only when i=j)

$^2$The transformed covariance matrix is:
$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{x^2 \text{$\sigma_{11}$}}{x^2+y^2} & -\frac{y^2 \text{$\sigma_{12}$}}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^{3/2}} \\
 -\frac{y^2 \text{$\sigma_{21}$}}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^{3/2}} & \frac{x^2 \text{$\sigma_{22}$}}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2} \\
\end{array}
\right)$

, with the complex number $z = x+iy$ and it's covariance matrix $\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \text{$\sigma_{11}$} & \text{$\sigma_{12}$} \\
 \text{$\sigma_{21}$} & \text{$\sigma_{22}$} \\
\end{array}
\right)$

3: Ok, I found this: With the covariance matrix, I'm getting in principle the covariance between the complex numbers but also the covariances between the real and imaginary parts. Looking from the Polar Point of View this means, I would have a $4x4 \epsilon \mathbb{R}$ matrix instead of the $2x2 \epsilon \mathbb{C}$.
My solution would be to handle this problem in polar-coordinate's view to get rid of the the cross-variances. Nevertheless I would really like to see how to do this proper (Assuming that I'm doing some silly thing at the moment...)

Comment: If you're getting imaginary covariances, then you're doing something wrong: most likely you are using transposes rather than Hermitian transposes.

Comment: Hermitian transpose is conjugate transpose, so $a + bi$ goes to $a - bi$. In the real case, Hermitian transpose is the same as transpose, but they differ in the complex case (and a bunch of theorems about real linear algebra that use transposes use conjugate transposes in the complex case).

Comment: Good idea! My start point is using the definition from wiki, where the covariance entries in the $i,j$-Matrix are given by (with $\mu=0$): $E([Z_i] [Z_j]^H)$. For any complex numbers $a + i b$ and $c + i d$ this becomes: $(a+ i b)(c - i d) = ac -bd + i(bc - ad)$ . And $bc - ad$ is not zero (Only where $i=j$)

Comment: Oh, I see, maybe there is a misunderstanding: I mean complex elements in the covariance-matrices and not pure imaginary.